# $(z_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$. |$z_n$| = 3 and Im $z_n$ is monotone. Prove that $(z_n)$ has min. one and max. 2 accumulation points.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm reading a math book and there is following exercise without a solution:

Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ satisyfying |$z_n$| = 3 and Im $z_n$ is monotone. Show that $(z_n)$ has at least one and at most two accumulation points.

I'm really struggling to see how someone would approach or solve such an exercise.

Please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Saad Oh ok. I was just so frustrated because I don't seem to find anything useful. Should I delete my question? Thanks.

Comment: The link above should give some general ideas on how to start solving a problem.

Comment: @smalllearner don't listen to him. He is just a typical stackexchange jerk. This is a justified and good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $\{z_n\}$ lie in the circle $C$ centered on the origin with radius equals to $3$ which is compact. Therefore it has at least one accumulation point.

If it has 3 accumulation points, then at least two of those have different imaginary parts $\alpha, \beta$: on a circle, at most two points have the same imaginary part. But as $z \to \Im z$ is continuous, $\{\Im z_n\}$ can't be monotonous.

Therefore $\{z_n\}$ has also at most two accumulation points.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,I am assuming the image set of the sequence is infinite,because if it's a constant sequence, it would satisfy the conditions, but still won't have a limit point.Now since $\{z_n\}$ is a sequence of complex numbers on the circle of radius $3$, which is compact, it must have atleast one limit point in $\{z:|z|=3\}$.Now, if a subsequence $\{z_{n_j}\}$ converges in the circle, it's imaginary parts must also converge,say to some $y$.Since the imaginary parts of the original sequence form a monotone sequence themselves, this implies that any limit point of the original sequence must lie on the line $\{z:Im(z)=y\}$.Since a line intersects a circle in atmost two points,we are done.

Comment: What is your definition of a limit point of a sequence? A constant sequence is convergent and has exactly one limit point.

Comment: By limit point of a set $A$ I mean a point $x$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ with $x$ itself deleted contains an element of $A$.In that sense,a constant sequence has no limit points.But I get your point too.It all comes down to what we prefer accepting as a definition,at the end of it.